# Reading a file into a string or array, then parse and use in a different class

Tags: android, arrays, serialization, arraylist

So, I am opening and reading files line by line, each line is currently read into a string, and the entire file is captured as another string which is simply the appended line strings. I don't need both, the point is that line and file strings are both available.

At the other end of this problem is a class which simply holds a string array, which is read and displayed by another activity. We can assume that each line in the file makes up another string in the array. This far, I have hard-coded text in this array, but obviously, I need to dynamically fill it with the line strings from the first activity.

I have seen how to sort-of make a dynamic array in java, but have never done so in an android app. I understand that an array list will fit the dynamic nature of unknown file lengths better, but what is the best way to get the lines into the subsequent class? I have serialized lists for listviews before - using getters and setters, but I can't get my head around how to just get from my line strings to array strings in another class. I have read 25+ posts and can use some help.

Here is the method that reads the file into strings, where you can see my two choices of strings from the opened file. The toasts are just for debug help.:

```
private void onFileClick(Option o) throws FileNotFoundException {
String filename = o.getName();
    String aDataRow;
    String aBuffer = null;

    Toast.makeText(this, "Selected: "+ currentDir + "/" + o.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {       
    File myFile = new File("/" + currentDir + "/" + filename);
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));       
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {  
        aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";         
    }        
    myReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),aBuffer,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent outlineInt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragActivity.class);
    startActivity(outlineInt);
    finish();
    }
```

Here's the class I need to get the strings into:

```
public class Content {

static String[] Paragraphs = {
    "Heading 1\n\nExcepteur pour-over occaecat squid biodiesel umami gastropub, nulla laborum salvia dreamcatcher fanny pack.\n\nUllamco culpa retro ea, trust fund excepteur eiusmod direct trade banksy nisi lo-fi cray messenger bag. Nesciunt esse carles selvage put a bird on it gluten-free, wes anderson ut trust fund twee occupy viral. Laboris small batch scenester pork belly, leggings ut farm-to-table aliquip yr nostrud iphone viral next level. Craft beer dreamcatcher pinterest truffaut ethnic, authentic brunch. Esse single-origin coffee banksy do next level tempor. Velit synth dreamcatcher, magna shoreditch in american apparel messenger bag narwhal PBR ennui farm-to-table.",
    "Heading 1\n\nVinyl williamsburg non velit, master cleanse four loko banh mi. Enim kogi keytar trust fund pop-up portland gentrify.\n\n Non ea typewriter dolore deserunt Austin. Ad magna ethical kogi mixtape next level. Aliqua pork belly thundercats, ut pop-up tattooed dreamcatcher kogi accusamus photo booth irony portland. Semiotics brunch ut locavore irure, enim etsy laborum stumptown carles gentrify post-ironic cray. Butcher 3 wolf moon blog synth, vegan carles odd future.",
    "Heading 2\n\nWhatever belongs in H2 goes here now",
    "Heading 3\n\nWhatever belongs in H3 goes here now",
    "Heading 4\n\nWhatever belongs in H4 finally goes here",
    "Heading 5\n\nExcepteur pour-over occaecat squid biodiesel umami gastropub, nulla laborum salvia dreamcatcher fanny pack.\n\nUllamco culpa retro ea, trust fund excepteur eiusmod direct trade banksy nisi lo-fi cray messenger bag.\n\nNesciunt esse carles selvage put a bird on it gluten-free, wes anderson ut trust fund twee occupy viral. Laboris small batch scenester pork belly, leggings ut farm-to-table aliquip yr nostrud iphone viral next level. Craft beer dreamcatcher pinterest truffaut ethnic, authentic brunch. Esse single-origin coffee banksy do next level tempor. Velit synth dreamcatcher, magna shoreditch in american apparel messenger bag narwhal PBR ennui farm-to-table.",

    };
}
```

Remember that I will never know how many lines ( or headings) there will be in any given file.

Any good ideas or experiences to share? Thanks.

Comment: There's an old principle that I applied here: If it seems too difficult to figure out, it's probably the wrong way to go. While this is still a good question, I solved this another way...